# Get IDs of list after inserting records to map to a second Object

Tags: apex, trigger

I have built a Trigger which first creates an Asset and then a Case when an Opportunity is Closed/Won. I however need to fill a field on Case, Asset.Id, with the ID of the Asset created in the same Trigger. How can I accomplish this?

I have tried going over the newly created List with another for loop, so for(Asset as : ast) {}, but then I just have the ID's in a List again. I also tried using trigger.newMap.keySet(), but then I will have them in a Map and I don't know how to acces them in the for loop of the Cases. I feel that there is an easy way to do this, I just don't know it yet.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

My code:

```
trigger CreateAssetonClosedWon on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
     for(Opportunity o: trigger.new){ 
      if(o.isWon == true && o.HasOpportunityLineItem == true){

         String opptyId = o.Id;
         OpportunityLineItem[] OLI = [Select Id, Quantity, PricebookEntry.Product2.Family, PricebookEntry.Product2Id, PricebookEntry.Product2.Name, Description, Converted_to_Case__c, Converted_to_Asset__c  
                                      From OpportunityLineItem 
                                      where OpportunityId = :opptyId  AND (Converted_to_Asset__c = false OR Converted_to_Case__c = false)];
         Asset[] ast = new Asset[]{};
         Asset a = new Asset();

         Case[] css = new Case[]{};
         Case c = new Case();

         for(OpportunityLineItem ol: OLI){
         if(ol.Converted_to_Asset__c == false){
            a = new Asset();
            a.AccountId = o.AccountId;
            a.Product2Id = ol.PricebookEntry.Product2Id;
            a.Quantity = ol.Quantity;
            ast.add(a);
            ol.Converted_to_Asset__c = true;
           }

           if(ol.Converted_to_Case__c == false){
            c = new Case();
            c.AccountId = o.AccountId;
            c.Opportunity__c = o.Id;  
            css.add(c);
            ol.Converted_to_Case__c = true;
           }

          insert ast;
          insert css;
          update OLI;
       }
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have few recommendations to your code:

- do not do SOQL or DML in loop;
- `ol.Converted_to_Asset__c == false` equivalent to `!ol.Converted_to_Asset__c`;
- declare new variables in places, where they will be used; for example, `Case c = new Case();` is declared to early, as you are going to use it only after `if` condition

---

if you would have external id on your assets, you would use [Creating Parent and Child Records in a Single Statement Using Foreign Keys](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_foreign_keys.htm). but this is not current case. So you need first to insert new assets, relate them to `OpprtunityLineItem` and this relationship will allow to get correct `Asset` Id for `Case` related to `OpprtunityLineItem`. This relationship is implemented by means of `assetsByOLIIdMap` `Map`.

```
trigger CreateAssetonClosedWon on Opportunity (after insert, after update){
    Set<Id> filteredOppIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Opportunity opp :trigger.new){
        if(opp.isWon && opp.HasOpportunityLineItem){
            filteredOppIds.add(opp.Id);
        }
    }
    List<OpportunityLineItem> olis = [
        select Id, OpportunityId, Quantity, PricebookEntry.Product2.Family, PricebookEntry.Product2Id, PricebookEntry.Product2.Name, Description, Converted_to_Case__c, Converted_to_Asset__c  
        from OpportunityLineItem 
        where OpportunityId = :filteredOppIds
            and (
                Converted_to_Asset__c = false 
                or
                Converted_to_Case__c = false
                )
        ];

    List<Case> casesToInsert = new List<Case>();
    Map<Id, Asset> assetsToInsertByOLIIdMap = new Map<Id, Asset>();

    for(OpportunityLineItem oli :olis){
        if(!oli.Converted_to_Asset__c){
            Asset newAsset = new Asset();
            newAsset.AccountId = Trigger.newMap.get(oli.OpportunityId).AccountId;
            newAsset.Product2Id = oli.PricebookEntry.Product2Id;
            newAsset.Quantity = oli.Quantity;
            oli.Converted_to_Asset__c = true;
            assetsToInsertByOLIIdMap.put(oli.Id, newAsset);
        }
    }
    insert assetsToInsertByOLIIdMap.values();

    for(OpportunityLineItem oli :olis){
        if(!oli.Converted_to_Case__c){
            Case newCase = new Case();
            newCase.AccountId = Trigger.newMap.get(oli.OpportunityId).AccountId;
            newCase.Opportunity__c = oli.OpportunityId;
            if(assetsToInsertByOLIIdMap.containsKey(oli.Id)){
                newCase.Asset__c = assetsToInsertByOLIIdMap.get(oli.Id).Id;
            }
            casesToInsert.add(newCase);
            oli.Converted_to_Case__c = true;
        }
    }
    insert casesToInsert;
    update olis;
}
```